# Limit activation of DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate to certain columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

Have a DataGrid with multiple columns.
Would like to limit activation of the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate to certain columns.
Actually I just want to exclude one column from activating the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RowDetailsVisibilityChanged` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailsvisibilitychanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and in event handler you can check selected column and hide or show row details.

In example below I don't want to show row details when I select cell in column "Name".

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="outerGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"                  
          RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="outerGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" >
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void outerGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null)
    {
        if (dg.CurrentCell != null && dg.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString() == "Name")
        {                    
            e.DetailsElement.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {   
            e.DetailsElement.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```